Focus issue in react chakra async select

react-select code
In first time input value is loss and after tying new word after show the options.

<AsyncSelect
  {...register(`formFields.${index}.product_id`)}
  menuPortalTarget={document.body}
  size="sm"
  placeholder="Select Product"
  variant={"outline"}
  borderColor={"gray.500"}
  value={field.value}
  //onKeyUp={() => totalCount()}
  onChange={(value) => {
    handleProductChange(value);
  }}
  loadOptions={(inputValue, callback) => {`your text`
    debouncedMultiProductsOptions(inputValue, callback);
  }}
  defaultOptions={defaultProducts}
/>

